# How will I Calling a particular value from other function for using in another function Visual Basic?

Tags: excel, vb.net, inheritance

I am using Visual Basic.I have two functions. I am creating a excel file and I assign a value in first function. after that, I need to reach a that value's cell and get the data in second function. But I can not reach it. How can i do that ?
First Function :

```
Public Function FirstFunction As String:
        Dim xls As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlsworkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlsworksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        xls = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlsworksheet = xlsworkbook.Worksheets("Template")
End Function
```

Second Function:

```
Public Function SecondFunction As String:
    Dim a1 As String = xlsworksheet.Range("A1").Value2
    xlsworksheet.Cells(B,2) = a1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you need to send values from a function to another...
The way to do this is

```
' If you don't need a value to be returned, use SUB instead
Public Sub FirstFunction As String
    
    Dim DataLeave As String = "Sending this to 2nd function"

    MsgBox(SecondFunction(DataLeave)) ' Will print "Now I need this"
End Sub



Public Function SecondFunction(DataEnter As String) As String
    Msgbox(DataEnter) ' Will print: "Sending this to 2nd function"

    DataEnter = "Now I need this"
            
    Return DataEnter
End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much. I will check that. I havent get enough. I will try and I will give you a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding about your question is you want to access that worksheet object in another function.
You can achieve that by two ways either you define your excel `xlsworksheet` object globally

```
public class YourClassName 
        Dim xls As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlsworkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlsworksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        Public Function FirstFunction As String:
             xls = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
             xlsworksheet = xlsworkbook.Worksheets("Template")
        End Function

        Public Function SecondFunction As String:
            if not isnothing(xlsworksheet)
                Dim a1 As String = xlsworksheet.Range("A1").Value2
                xlsworksheet.Cells(B,2) = a1
            End if 
        End function

End Class
```

or

You can pass reference of that object to another function.
One more thing you haven't return anything then why are you using `function` instead `Sub`

```
Public Function FirstFunction As String:
        Dim xls As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlsworkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlsworksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        xls = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlsworksheet = xlsworkbook.Worksheets("Template")
        secondFunction(xlsworksheet )
End Function

Public Function SecondFunction (byref xlsworksheet as  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)  As String:
    Dim a1 As String = xlsworksheet.Range("A1").Value2
    xlsworksheet.Cells(B,2) = a1
End function
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think passing the reference of object is going to work. I wrote these functions for example. I am working on a big project and actually these functions are over 300 lines but I wanted to describe my problem. So I wrote these functions. I am returning some values also.